# Title bar keeps appearing, even with requestWindowFeature or android:theme

Tags: android, splash-screen, titlebar, custom-titlebar

My question is exactly the sabe as [Custom titlebar - system titlebar being shown for a brief moment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950901/custom-titlebar-system-titlebar-being-shown-for-a-brief-moment)

But I couldn't achieve the same results as @Jerry wrote on best answer. "When I switched to using a theme to tell the framework I didn't want a title, the problem went away and I now see my own title directly on first load"

My code:

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="3" android:versionName="1.0.2"
package="androidhive.dashboard"     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application android:icon="@drawable/icone" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity 
        android:name="com.androidhive.dashboard.SplashScreen"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
style="@style/SplashTheme"
 >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/splashscreen_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
android:contentDescription="Splash"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:src="@drawable/splash"
style="@style/SplashTheme" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Style:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="@android:Theme.Black">
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:background">@drawable/splash</item>
</style>
```

SplashScreen.java

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity implements Runnable{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setTheme(R.style.SplashTheme);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen_layout);




    Handler h = new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(this, 15000);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, AndroidDashboardDesignActivity.class));
    finish();
}
}
```

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Under your application tab, not your activity one

Comment: It's so simple so only author can understand himself!

Answer (score 9):

Use your theme in your activity on the AndroidManifest not in your Layout!!

This will work:
SplashScreen.java

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity{


    private Handler handler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);

        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                   Intent intent=new Intent(SplashScreen.this, AndroidDashboardDesignActivity.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   finish();

            }
        };
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);


    }
```

theme.xml

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="SplashTheme.FullScreen" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

the first theme will show the status bar for you if you want to hide this one also use the second theme.Also i have used the attribute windowBackround to null because you will use your image as a backround for your RootLayout after that, so it's better to not override the background color used by the default android theme for performance issue.

in your splashscreen_layout you can use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

In your manifest use this

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icone"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.androidhive.dashboard.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

if you want to use the second theme change in your manifest

`android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"` with `android:theme="@style/SplashTheme.FullScreen"`

A Simple way remove or you style tag in your layout and add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` in your Manifest under activity tag

Comment: Thank you! As long as I didn't want a custom title, @Cruceo's answer worked fine. But yours is very complete and well-explained, and may help those who want custom titles.

Answer (score 1):

With `AppCompat` this seems works differently.

Following solution worked for me:

Add new theme style with no action bar in your `styles.xml` and set `parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"`.

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>

</style>
```

Now implement the same theme style to your splash screen activity in `androidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
        android:name=".ActivityName"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"> // apply splash them here 

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Here is result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

based on Krunal solution you can simply put this line inside the `<activity>` tag in activity.xml file:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

I.E.
 replace:
`android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"`

with:

`android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"`

inside

```
<activity
        android:name=".ActivityName"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"> // replace this line

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

giving:

```
<activity
            android:name=".ActivityName"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"> // line replaced

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

this saves you from adding anything to styles.xml .

Answer (score 0):

**In your MainActivity use this**

```
 getSupportActionBar().hide();
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```